# Wordpress core file changed

Tags: wordpress, security, cookies, varnish

I get an alert from wordfence that one of the Wordpress core files has changed. Its about wp-login.php
Some lines about cookies were #commented since the 23th. See image.

I asked my hoster about it if they did it, because i have a running support ticket about woocommerce,varnish and cookies with them.
But they say they don't know.

Now i'm wondering are there plugins that edit core files? and what is the #commented code about?

So that i have a better understanding where i'm standing in this situation. I dont think i'm hacked. But any advice would be helpful.

[compared files wordfence screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO7ou.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, it is not related to programing as defined in the scope of stackOverFlow…

Comment: Possibly some one got access of your files by some kind of vulnerabilities, better update your word-press version. Also check which all plugin you had added recently.